# handling byte array of image in node js server

Tags: ios, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am following this below library for my applications where user have to chat with other user.

[SocketChat](https://github.com/appcoda/SocketIOChat)

There I can chat with other users. Now my prime concern is to send images to server and then that image is going to reflect in the chat of the other user's window. Its like Group chat.

I am done with image sending from iOS app

I don't know what to write to handle byte array which is of the image I sent from one of the client.

```
  clientSocket.on('images', function(clientNickname, message){
  var currentDateTime = new Date().toLocaleString();
  var dataType = "imageType"

  delete typingUsers[clientNickname];
  io.emit("userTypingUpdate", typingUsers);
  io.emit('newChatMessage', clientNickname, message, currentDateTime,dataType);
  });
```

I think its not working. Its good for the string type data. Can you please let me know what to write there in order to receive image and send that back.

Comment: You need a format to transport the binary data over the text based http protocol ;) Standard is Base64 Encoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: @ReneM. you mean I have to convert the data to base64 string and then send to server? If yes, I have tried but some times, it comes back and some times it not. One more thing is NsData is relatively small that base64 string

Comment: That's the out goes.

Comment: What should I do then @ReneM.

Comment: First read the complete specification of base64, read some best practice guids for your used languages on client and server side. Look up possible libraries or already existing API methods you cam use to do Base64 Encoding and Decoding. Then impl. a test for client encoding and server decoding, decoupled from your project. To make it work. When this works, your knowledge is now good enough to use it in your project. One advice the bytes aren't enough, for an image you should also know the mime type to select the correct file extention and image decoder/encoder.

Comment: Working good now. I am sending NSData now!!

Comment: If anyone want to know my implementation he can ping me here..